# dokku: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: nginx, dokku

I keep getting the "413 Request Entity Too Large" error when uploading files that are larger than 1M.  I followed the following instructions from [here](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/) but it didn't work.

```
mkdir /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/
echo 'client_max_body_size 50M;' > /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
service nginx reload
```

I tried updating my `Procfile` adding a php.ini file to my root directory with the following entry but it also didn't help:

Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf -i php.ini php/
```

php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there anyway to test if my configurations are being used or if they are being overwritten by something else?  I checked `phpinfo();` and those setting are being used, is there an equivalent to that for nginx?

Is there a way to change the nginx settings globally for all images?

Comment: what do nginx log say? And possible for you to check if nginx had that setting applied by running `nginx -T` on the machine where nginx is running

Answer (score 15):

Dokku's default nginx config limits the client max body size to to 1MB.

You can reconfigure this by:

```
mkdir /home/dokku/node-js-app/nginx.conf.d/
echo 'client_max_body_size 50m;' > /home/dokku/node-js-app/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/node-js-app/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
service nginx reload
```

Where `node-js-app` is the app name. See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/#customizing-via-configuration-files-included-by-the-default-tem

Comment: Thank's I tried to set with nginx:set <app> <property> (<value>)  but it's not possible. Your solution is correct.